# how to draw upside down traingle with curvy point

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-clippath

I tried this code

```
 Path getClip(Size size) {

    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
```

But I didn't got perfect output

```
 Path getClip(Size size) {

    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
```

But I want this shape

[image: login screen's appbar]

Comment: Try this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!!!

**Solution 1:**

**Output**
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InvertedTriangle extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 350,
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
              ),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: const Text(
              "Lorem Ipsum",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          CustomPaint(
            painter: InvertedTrianglePainter(),
            size: Size(350, 350),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InvertedTrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double width = size.width;
    final double height = size.height;

    final double bluntHeight =
        height * 0.19; // Adjust the blunt height as per your requirement
    final double bluntOffset =
        width * 0.022; // Adjust the blunt offset as per your requirement

    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0); // Top left corner

    path.lineTo(width, 0); // Top right corner
    path.lineTo(width / 2 + bluntOffset, bluntHeight); // Top blunt corner
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      width / 2,
      bluntHeight * 1.06,
      width / 2 - bluntOffset,
      bluntHeight,
    ); // Curve the tip of the triangle
    path.lineTo(0, 0); // Top left corner
    path.close();

    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: InvertedTriangle(),
  ));
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InvertedTriangle extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Inverted Triangle'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: InvertedTrianglePainter(),
          size: Size(500, 500), // Adjust the size as per your requirement
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InvertedTrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double width = size.width;
    final double height = size.height;

    final double bluntHeight = height * 0.2; // Adjust the blunt height as per your requirement
    final double bluntOffset = width * 0.01; // Adjust the blunt offset as per your requirement

    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0); // Top left corner

    path.lineTo(width, 0); // Top right corner
    path.lineTo(width / 2 + bluntOffset, bluntHeight); // Top blunt corner
    path.lineTo(width / 2 - bluntOffset, bluntHeight); // Top blunt corner

    path.lineTo(0, 0); // Top left corner
    path.close();

    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: InvertedTriangle(),
  ));
}
```